# ONI to BAG and BAG to ONI

Tags: openni, rosbag

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Has somebody written a conversion method for this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/30319/oni-to-bag-and-bag-to-oni/) by [KoenBuys](https://answers.ros.org/users/134/koenbuys/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2314 on 2012-03-22

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) on 2012-03-24**:
Can you clarify what ONI is?

**Comment by [KoenBuys](https://answers.ros.org/users/134/koenbuys/) on 2012-03-27**:
This is the file format from the openni library.

**Comment by [Arrakis](https://answers.ros.org/users/2996/arrakis/) on 2012-08-31**:
I would also like to know how to achieve this functionality.  Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

great question. I was just thinking about writing one myself :)

---

Originally posted by [Moataz Elmasry](https://answers.ros.org/users/116/moataz-elmasry/) with karma: 126 on 2013-01-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0